# Any way to see what cookies a site with redirects sets using Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I have a web site that I am having a hard time whitelisting to use cookies because I think it is using a third party cookie after doing redirects. So, in other words what happens is that the web site, which is a library portal, asks for a login, then redirects to the requested service and along the way one or more third party cookies are set. Unless these cookies are set, then the redirect fails. Thus, currently the only way I can use the web site is to turn off cookie blocking entirely, which I don't want to do.

What I want to do is whitelist whatever cookie the library is relying on so I can use the portal without turning off generic cookie blocking. To do this I need to know what the domain is that wants to set the cookie.

One way to determine this is to delete all the cookies on my machine, turn off cookie blocking, access the resource, then see what cookies got set. But, I do not want to do this because I have hundreds of cookies on my machines many of which are for logins and I would have to relogin to every one of those dozens of sites if I delete all the cookies on my machine.

How can find out what cookies the libary is using without deleting all my cookies? I am using Chrome.

Comment: if you just tell us the domain, maybe we can try to help.. one more thing - you can tell us a little more about your cookie blocker, maybe there is a feature or something right for this cases

Comment: I think Fiddler will tell you about the setcookie commands executed by which domain.

Comment: @FrankThomas I DON'T KNOW THE DOMAIN. That's the whole point. The portal does multiple redirects through unknown domains that are setting cookies. I need to find out what those domains are so I can whitelist their cookies.

Comment: that's exactly what fiddler will tell you. it is a debugging proxy that will show you all your network connections and will show you HTTP information like cookie settings, etc.

Comment: You can simply look at what chrome is doing with F12 developer tools. It’s all there.